# Is it possible to share a bucket only with another user in another Google cloud account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to share a bucket and its contents with another user who is having a different gcloud account?

This person does not belong to the gcloud account that I'm using and has his own account and project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Using Identity and Access Management (IAM) Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) you can see how to control who has access to your buckets and objects. Please follow the instructions in [Adding a Member to a bucket-level policy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-add):

> 1. Open the Cloud Storage browser in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
> 2. Click the drop-down menu associated with the bucket to which you want to grant a member a role. The drop-down menu appears as three
>      vertical dots to the far right of the bucket's row.
> 3. Choose Edit bucket permissions.
> 4. In the Add members field, enter one or more identities that need access to your bucket.
> 5. Select a role (or roles) from the Select a role drop-down menu. The roles you select appear in the pane with a short description of the
>      permissions they grant.
> 6. Click Add.

This will allow your colleague to interact with the contents of your bucket in the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/) or terminal with [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) installed. To see the objects in the Cloud Storage Browser you can share the link to your bucket (taking for granted that your colleague has the permissions as described above), i.e.:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/my-bucket-name
```

Please see the referenced docs to see all the options on how to perform this.